# Phabricator error: unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory when Git push?

Tags: git, repository, git-push, phabricator

I was installed **Phabricator** on my VM, all settings are working correctly. I made git repo on there, and I can *clone*, *fetch*, *pull* successfully.

But I got an error when I try to *push* with this description:

```
error: unpack failed: unable to create a temporary object directory
To http://xxx.yyy.co.id/source/phabricator_docs.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://xxx.yyy.co.id/source/phabricator_docs.git'
```

Here's some Phabricator setting :
"diffusion.allow-http-auth": true,
"repository.default-local-path": "/opt/phab/repo"

I try to change permission and change the owner of repository dir, but it still got an error.

I'm so depressed about how to solve this error. Because this Phabricator will be used by our employee soon. Hope this question will get an answer and solve my problem.